# Java MySQL syntax error that wont go away

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new to MySQL and I'm trying to implement it in my Java code. What I want to do is for a method to be called, and the database table updated/inserted into, based on whether the record already exists.

Now, I've taken a look around StackOverflow and Goggle, and from what I found, I need to ensure I remove spaces between values in my command, and that each value if prefixed and suffixed by a '. However, this doesn't seem to cut it. I still get an error saying `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`

I don't know why this is because I am following the syntax that I saw on tutorial sites and forums, but it seems to still be incorrect. I know it's not my host that's the problem because I can connect to and query it easily. Here's my code:

```
                if (!syncedPlayers.contains(player)) {
                worked = database.command("INSERT INTO " +
                        TABLE_NAME + " " + UUID_FIELD + "," + CAPTURE_FIELD + "," + FFA_FIELD + "," + GEANT_FIELD + "," + QUIZZ_FIELD + "," + SURVIE_FIELD +
                        " VALUES ('" + player.toString() + "','" +
                        getScores(CAPTURE_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "','" +
                        getScores(FFA_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "','" +
                        getScores(GEANT_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "','" +
                        getScores(QUIZZ_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "','" +
                        getScores(SURVIE_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "'");
            } else {
                worked = database.command(
                        "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME +
                                " SET " + field + " = '" + getScores(field, player, field, amount) +
                                "' WHERE " + UUID_FIELD + " = '" + player.toString() + "'");
            }
```

Each `getScores(<FIELD>, <UUID>, <FIELD2>, <INTEGER>` always returns an integer value. So you can imagine them as just 35s or 123 or 0 etc. I am also using an SQL wrapper called SpigotLib which simplifies java SQL.

I am a complete newbie to SQL, so please don't be offended if this looks like such a simple question.

Comment: You are missing `()` around the column names in the `INSERT` statement, and `)` at the end. Your SQL is `INSERT INTO table col1, col2 VALUES (val2, val2`, but it should be `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val2, val2)`.

Comment: Consider printing the SQL statements before attempting to execute them -- it will help you spot syntax errors.

Comment: Are you missing a closing bracket after your `VALUES (.....` ?

Comment: `which simplifies java SQL` - Your code is everything but simple. You might have a look at prepared statements, they would make your code much more clear and your SQL much safer.

Comment: Agree with @BackSlash: You should use `PreparedStatement` and `?` parameter markers, so prevent [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks where hackers can **steal your data** and delete your tables.

Comment: This is the wrong way to construct a SQL request in JDBC.  You should be using PreparedStatement.  It'll escape strings and dates for you properly, bind variables, and guard against SQL injection.

Comment: If you simply printed out your SQL you would be able to see whether it looks right or not.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys for the helpful comments, I will make the adjustments to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never closed the `VALUES (`

your last line should be

```
getScores(SURVIE_FIELD, player, field, amount) + "')");
```